# jQuery remove element not working onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code that gets generated in PHP.

```
            <?php
        foreach ($quote->lineItems as $lineItem) {
            $name = "line_item_" . rand();
            $txtValue = "Supplier: " . $lineItem->supplierName . " Model: " . $lineItem->modelName . " Price: " . $lineItem->price . " Quantity: " . $lineItem->quantity;
            ?>
            <table style="width:900px">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='hidden' name='<?= $name ?> id='<?= $name ?>''
                        value='<?= $lineItem->id ?>,<?= $lineItem->supplierId ?>,<?= $lineItem->supplierName ?>
                        ,<?= $lineItem->modelId ?>,<?= $lineItem->modelName ?>,<?= $lineItem->price ?>
                        ,<?= $lineItem->quantity ?>'/>
                        <?= $txtValue ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type='button' onclick="onBtnRemove('<?= $name ?>')" class="btn btn-secondary">
                            Remove
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

The onBtnRemove function looks like this.

```
        function onBtnRemove(idToRemove) {
            const toRemove = $("#" + idToRemove);
            toRemove.remove();
        }
```

I cannot figure out why the element does not remove.

[image]

Comment: Was that a copy and paste of the code? Because you have a quote in the wrong spot. It should be: `name='<?= $name ?>' id='<?= $name ?>'`

Comment: Can you please show all the code?

Comment: I wouldn't use a const, just `$("#" + idToRemove).remove()` is enough, you should console.log(idToRemove) just to see if you're not passing it with the `#`.